# How can i get the value of my labelString?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I get the String value of labelString and use it to ToastmakeText(labelString), when I try to get the value from another class my application keeps crashing.

Tracker.java

```
     if(!isVisible) {
      return;
    }
    for (final TrackedRecognition recognition : trackedObjects) {
      final RectF trackedPos = new RectF(recognition.location);

      boxPaint.setColor(recognition.color);
      boxPaint.setAlpha(200);

      //float cornerSize = Math.min(trackedPos.width(), trackedPos.height()) / 15.0f;
      //canvas.drawRoundRect(trackedPos, cornerSize, cornerSize, boxPaint);
      canvas.drawRect(trackedPos, boxPaint);

      String labelString = !TextUtils.isEmpty(recognition.title) ?
              String.format("%s", recognition.title) : "";
      if (showConfidence) {
        labelString = String.format("%s%s", labelString, String.format(Locale.ENGLISH," %.1f%%", (100 * recognition.detectionConfidence)));
      }
      borderedText.drawText(
              canvas, trackedPos.left, trackedPos.top, labelString, boxPaint);
              textMe = labelString;
    }}
```

CameraActivity.java error found

```
           String speak = tracker.textMe;

    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            //show no error
            if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                //Speak
                //Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, speak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //mTTS.speak(speak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
                runnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //do something
                        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000l);
                        Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, speak, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mTTS.speak(speak,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);

                    }
                };
                handler.post(runnable);
                //Connection Handler?

                    handler.post(runnable);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Logcat error I found

> 2022-06-05 14:47:12.434 12123-12123/at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.debug
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.debug, PID: 12123
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.debug/at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.CameraActivity}:
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field
> 'java.lang.String at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.tracking.Tracker.textMe' on a
> null object reference
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3846)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'java.lang.String at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.tracking.Tracker.textMe'
> on a null object reference
> at at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.CameraActivity.onCreate(CameraActivity.java:290)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
> at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130) 
> 2022-06-05 14:47:17.613 12123-12242/at.tuwien.ict.eml.odd.debug
> W/System: A resource failed to call close.

Comment: I tried to get the labelString value from another class I'm sorry I didn't tell it yesterday. The application keep crashing when I tried to get a value from it.

Comment: According to the stack trace, line 290 in file `CameraActivity.java` is throwing a `NullPointerException`. [Edit] your question and indicate which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: The exception seems pretty unrelated to the code. Is your code from CameraActivity.java? / Is CameraActivity.java your own class?

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out I added the codes from CameraActivity where the error appeared.